# CreateSQLQuery() not executing

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am attempting to delete a specific row w/

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("DELETE FROM [dbo].[UserTable] WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' ").ExecuteUpdate();
```

but it does not seem to execute the command, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a transaction and commit after the `ExecuteUpdate`.  See the [NHibernate reference docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#quickstart-playingwithcats) or [this Ayende post](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions) for example usage.

If still no luck after that, try a [profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to see what SQL, if any, NHibernate is executing.

Note: it's always recommended to use a transaction w/ NHibernate, even if you're just reading data.